# Is it safe to dump a specific key of redis bloom-filter to other database like mongodb?

Tags: redis, bloom-filter, redis-stack

The reason why I want to do this is that we have a lot of cold data and it takes a lot of memory.

I've tried Redis server v5.0.8 and the server crushed as described here [redis bloom issue#672](https://github.com/RedisBloom/RedisBloom/issues/672), I also tried v=6.2.13 the latest release of redis/redis-stack-server and It appears to be functioning, but I am not sure if it has some hidden issues, and actually we are using v5.0.8 in production. So I want to know:

- Is it safe to dump the bloom filter to other databases like MongoDB and restore it?
- Can I dump and load them between different Redis versions?

Below is the pseudocode I used for testing:

```golang
items := bson.A{}
var iterPointer int64 = 0
for {
    iter, data, err := rb.BfScanDump(key, iterPointer)
    iterPointer = iter
    if err != nil {
        return items, err
    }
    if iter == 0 {
        break
    }

    items = append(items, bson.M{"iter": iter, "data": hex.EncodeToString(data)})
}

// then store it in Mongo, and read the items out and hex.DecodeString(data) to restore it.
```

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is "_frequently_" and "_barely_" to you?

Comment: I just added some additional information.

Comment: Auto Tiering seems like a suitable choice, but unfortunately, I am not using Redis Enterprise.